# Understanding why does sometime "NULL" and sometime "Empty" value is stored to same field?

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, web-applications, spring-mvc, null

Currently I am working on spring(MVC) web app, I have observed something strange while validating entity class fields in my controller. Whenever i try to do validation after each form submittion i get confused about the value that is stored in entity class fields.

Example, following is the code snippet i use for validating one of the string field. It works fine, but sometimes not. Reason i found is sometime there is `Null value` set and sometime `Empty value` is set for the `same field`.

```
if(entity.getWhoBookedIt().equals("")){
  bindingResult.rejectValue("whoBookedIt", "NotEmpty.java.lang.String", null, null);
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening?, can anybody explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not really answer your question, but as a solution you could use Apache's StringUtils class to check for both.

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(entity.getWhoBookedIt()){
    bindingResult.rejectValue("whoBookedIt", "NotEmpty.java.lang.String", null, null);
}
```

From the StringUtils class:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: Thanks for answering!, right now i am using StringUtils itself. But i need to know the reason why this is happening.